# Why is my IF(AND) nesting generating incorrect results?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

this may be a fairly simple one but I have spent a significant amount of time troubleshooting my formula and cannot identify as to why it is not returning the desired result.

I am working with two columns of data (A and B) which reference deals that my team is working on. Column A denotes the team member who is allocated to said transaction, and column B states whether or not the transaction is currently live ("TRUE" or "FALSE"). I am looking to return the email address for said team member if the transaction is live ("TRUE"). There are three team members contained within the spreadsheet, so I am nesting several AND functions.

I have tried the following code:

```
=
IF(AND(A1="TRUE",B1="Name1"),"name1.lastname1@x.com",
IF(AND(A1="TRUE",B1="Name2"),"name2.lastname2@x.com",
IF(AND(A1="TRUE",B1="Name3"),"name3.lastname3@x.com",0)))
```

The formula is returning "0" for each value, despite some of them meeting the relevant conditions.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: remove the quotes around the `TRUE`

Comment: Or just `AND(A1,B1=...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just mixed up the columns.

Swap `B1` and `A1` expressions.